# How can I redirect stdout to a parent script in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I have:

ScriptA.**sh** calling scriptB.**sh** calling ScriptC.**py**

ScriptA waits for scriptB that waits for ScriptC to replay success.

The python return with a string every 3 min in case that his operation did not succeed (regular output).

Those outputs are aggregated into ScriptB's buffer. I would like to redirect them, on the fly, to ScriptA's log.

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you clarify?   The output of Script B will be in Script A's log, right?   So all script B has to do is to print *its* buffer to the screen, and because that's output of script B, then Script A will be able to see it.

Comment: If you just want B to write to file A, you'd open file A as a file object with "w" or "r+" and then set the STDOUT of the B subprocess to the file object.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, yes,the output of Script B will be in Script A's log. The issue is that the user is monitoring logA only so in the waiting time, I would like to print the output of scriptC to that log..

Comment: @AvivYamSimhay, but if Script B does no redirection whatsoever, its output will go to the stdout it inherited from its parent. If that stdout is itself already directed to Script A's log, then... well, why do you have to do anything at all to get the behavior you want?

Comment: In short -- this is something where a reproducer showing how you get into a situation where Script B's output isn't **already** going to Script A's log **by default** would help ensure that answers are actually relevant.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `tee`:

> tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

For example, in ScriptB.sh:

```
while read someLine; do
    ...
done < <( ScriptC.py | tee -a logfileOfScriptA )
```

I don't know how you're calling the scripts, but this is what `tee` is for.

Edited -- I think @Charles Duffy is saying something like this if you want to get fancy:

```
$ cat ScriptA.sh 
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=ScriptA.out

exec 5>>$LOGFILE

./ScriptB.sh
$ cat ScriptB.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello, world!' | tee >(cat - >&5)
$ ./ScriptA.sh 
Hello, world!
$ cat ScriptA.out 
Hello, world!
```

Comment: This assumes that script A actually logs to a file -- not to a socket, not to a pipeline, not to... whatever other odd thing it might be. A better solution might be to back up the original inherited FD (so you don't need to care whether that FD attaches to a file/pipe/socket/whatever) and tee into that.

Comment: If only targeting Linux, one might also consider `tee /dev/fd/5`, thus avoiding the overhead of the `cat` process. Of course, all of this is assuming that the log isn't written to by FD 1 already; since the OP hasn't provided a reproducer, we don't have a very good idea of what their actual environment (and thus, their actual question) is.

Comment: Agreed... sometimes you've got to throw some ideas out there and see what sticks. Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Tx for all the help!

I resolved the issue by installing: "yum install expect" where ScriptB is running (not the same server), then implement the following:

```
ScriptA{

unbuffer /path/to/ScriptB

}
```